# Analyze .class files

Tags: java, class, methods, java-bytecode-asm

I want to know if there is a way to get the number of calls to a certain method in .class files.

I have searched and I found tools like ASM and sonarqube but I don't find the way to obtain the information I need.

Thank you

Comment: Are you taling about static or dynamic information? Do you want to kow how often a method is mentioned in the `.class` itself or do you want to know how many times a method is called while executing?

Comment: You can use ASM to visit the code and count the number of times that the method is mentioned.  If you want to know this information at runtime, I suggest using an aspect orientated library to do this.  You can as ASM (as these libraries do) but a higher level library would be easier.

Comment: I´m trying to do static analysis. Trying to count the number of times that the method is mentioned into the classes

Answer (score 0):

**Byte Code Injection**

->>> Inject your counting code inside the class where you want to monitor.

For byte code injection you can use ASM or JavaAssit.

http://java.dzone.com/articles/implementing-build-time

Comment: Thank you very much butI think that i will not work for me.

With your solution I will see how much times the method is called with the application running but I want to do static analysis. With my proyect compiled I want to see how much times a method is called into the classes

Answer (score 0):

[image: You Problem Definition Right]

**Solution :**
Try Below Code, you will get a hint to traverse through byte code. If you made a close look you can see how many times the your method is used in the code. For that you can even use Regex.

```
package com.cosmic.evaluate.asm;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader;
import org.objectweb.asm.util.ASMifier;
import org.objectweb.asm.util.TraceClassVisitor;

public class TetsMain {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

String classPath =       "./target/classes/com/cosmic/evaluate/asm/TestClass.class";

    int flags = ClassReader.SKIP_DEBUG;


    ClassReader cr;

    if (classPath.endsWith(".class") || classPath.indexOf('\\') > -1 || classPath.indexOf('/') > -1) {
        cr = new ClassReader(new FileInputStream(classPath));
    } else {
        cr = new ClassReader(classPath);
    }

    cr.accept(new TraceClassVisitor(null, new ASMifier(), new PrintWriter(System.out)), flags);

}

}
```

**Maven Dependency Used**
    
      org.ow2.asm
      asm-all
      5.0.3

**Links**
[Tutorial for Regular Expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/)